# com.google.code.gson cannot parse tamil results

Tags: java, gson, telegram-bot, tamil

So, I'm trying to fetch JSON results from https://api-thirukkural.vercel.app/api?num=1139 using [Java-Telegram-Bot-Api](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) and send it to telegram. I use [com.google.code.gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) dependency for parsing JSON.

The expected results from API:

```
{"number":1139,"sect_tam":"காமத்துப்பால்","chapgrp_tam":"களவியல்","chap_tam":"நாணுத் துறவுரைத்தல்","line1":"அறிகிலார் எல்லாரும் என்றேஎன் காமம்","line2":"மறுகின் மறுகும் மருண்டு.","tam_exp":"என்னைத் தவிர யாரும் அறியவில்லை என்பதற்காக என் காதல் தெருவில் பரவி மயங்கித் திரிகின்றது போலும்!","sect_eng":"Love","chapgrp_eng":"The Pre-marital love","chap_eng":"Declaration of Love's special Excellence","eng":"My perplexed love roves public street Believing that none knows its secret","eng_exp":"And thus, in public ways, perturbed will rove"}
```

Here is a piece of my java code:

```
  String results = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        String apiUrl = "https://api-thirukkural.vercel.app/api?num=" + random.nextInt(1329 + 1);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                results += sc.nextLine();
            }
            sc.close();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[" + results + "]");
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            message.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
            message.setText("Number: " + object.getInt("number") + "\n\n" + object.getString("line1") + "\n"
                    + object.getString("line2") + "\n\n" + object.getString("tam_exp") + "\n\n" + object.getString("eng_exp"));
            conn.disconnect();
            execute(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The result in telegram:

```
Number: 1139

à®…à®±à®¿à®•à®¿à®²à®¾à®°à¯� à®Žà®²à¯�à®²à®¾à®°à¯�à®®à¯� à®Žà®©à¯�à®±à¯‡à®Žà®©à¯� à®•à®¾à®®à®®à¯�
à®®à®±à¯�à®•à®¿à®©à¯� à®®à®±à¯�à®•à¯�à®®à¯� à®®à®°à¯�à®£à¯�à®Ÿà¯�.

à®Žà®©à¯�à®©à¯ˆà®¤à¯� à®¤à®µà®¿à®° à®¯à®¾à®°à¯�à®®à¯� à®…à®±à®¿à®¯à®µà®¿à®²à¯�à®²à¯ˆ à®Žà®©à¯�à®ªà®¤à®±à¯�à®•à®¾à®• à®Žà®©à¯� à®•à®¾à®¤à®²à¯� à®¤à¯†à®°à¯�à®µà®¿à®²à¯� à®ªà®°à®µà®¿ à®®à®¯à®™à¯�à®•à®¿à®¤à¯� à®¤à®¿à®°à®¿à®•à®¿à®©à¯�à®±à®¤à¯� à®ªà¯‹à®²à¯�à®®à¯�!

And thus, in public ways, perturbed will rove
```

Is this a problem in gson dependency? Can someone help me fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the Charset on Scanner. That is probably the problem.

Example:

```
new Scanner(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

You should use the Charset that fits.